# problema con visualización de imagen en pagina

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un módulo de carga de imágenes de productos hacia un servidor ftp, si la carga tuvo exito, guardo la ruta de la imagen en mi bd ejemplo "imagenes/producto1.jpg", si la ruta se guarda exitosamente, consulto a esa bd y esta me devuelve la ruta.

El problema es que cuando seteo el valor en la etiqueta img, en realidad no se muestra la que se cargo , sino la que trae por defecto, he mirado en el ftp y efectivamente se carga y también se guarda la ruta en la bd.

El código esta de más ponerlo, pues todo funciona bien, sólo que la imagen que actualizo no se muestra en la página, simplemente se ve la que viene por defecto, pero si sirve de algo, esta es la línea de codigo en donde seteo en la propiedad src de la etiqueta la ruta de la imagen en el ftp.

```
echo '<img id="ImgProd'.trim($entry->CodProd).'" src="ftp://'.$_SESSION["UserFtp"].':'.$_SESSION["pass"].'@'.$_SESSION["Serverftp"].'/'.trim($entry->Ruta).'/'.trim($entry->Img).'" style="height:auto; max-width: 90%" class="form-control" name="sImagen" />';
```

Comment: Hola. Tu código contiene errores, he editado la pregunta sin tocar el código, sólo lo he puesto en forma de nota para que se vea más claro. Ejemplo a CodProd le falta una comilla simple antes del punto: `'CodProd).'" src="ftp://'.$_SESSION["UserFtp"]...`. Para más claridad sería mejor que todos los valores que tienes en `$_SESSION[...`los almacenes en variables y luego uses esas variables para concatenar. Revisa eso y si no te funciona vuelve por aquí. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso hay algunas situaciones que debes considerar:

1. Si actualizas la foto en la bd, lo ideal es recargar la página para que entonces descargue con base en la nueva ruta.
2. Si lo anterior lo haces, entonces debes tomar en cuenta que si estas utilizando las variables de `$_SESSION` para almacenar la ruta en el momento de actualizar la imagen también debes actualizar la variable `$_SESSION`
3. Por último si estas haciendo lo anterior, hay otra situación que influye, esta se encamina más al nombre con el que estas guardando tu archivo por ejemplo imagen1.jpg. Si al momento de actualizar subes la nueva imagen con el mismo nombre "imagen1.jpg" lo más seguro es que tu navegador considere que la imagen no ha cambiado y por tanto mantega en memoria caché lo anterior.

Si este es el caso, lo que yo creo más probable, debes entonces guardar la actualización con un nuevo nombre para que lo vuelva a descargar el navegador

Comment: eso es exactamente lo que estoy pensando Luis, pero no puedo ponerle otro nombre porque en el formato en el que la guardo es con su código ejemplo "00001.jpg" , y es así poque la trabajo de esa manera en otros módulos lo de la ruta en las variables de sesion, con eso no hay problema

Comment: Considerando lo que me comentas he encontrado cuatro posibles soluciones que pueden solucionar tu probllema, quiz la más secilla sería la opcion 2 donde simplemente agregas un sufijo a la url de tu imagen
por ejemplo estas 2 URL te dirigen al mismo lugar pero son diferentes
----  https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png  ----
----  https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png?t=300317----


http://stackoverflow.com/a/22429796/6620565

Comment: eso fue lo que se me ocurrió , generar un numero aleatorio con rand() si  y funciono , de todos modos muchas gracias gracias por tu ayuda, ya había considerado la cache como problema, pero no estaba seguro, gracias de verdad ! @Luis Andrés Juarez Sandoval

Comment: De nada, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

problema de cache, el navegador al ver que la URL es la misma no hacia el cambio, lo que soluciono ese problema fue generar un numero ramdon y pasárselo como sufijo a la URL de la imagen, ejemplo "Imagen00001.jpg?0125"